# Adding an html element using javascript makes other js wonky

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, swfupload

I have the following javascript code, which is modified from the SimpleUpload demo in SWFUpload. It's used to generate a temporary upload progress bar. It works fine, unless I add in the code which has been commented out. Basically, this line will break the presentation:

> this.fileProgressElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Upload Status"));

Demos: Try out the upload. The upload functionality does not work.
http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/uploader-works/upload_files.php
http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/uploader-broken/upload_files.php

The code is: 
[http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/uploader-works/js/sample1.txt](http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/uploader-broken/js/sample1.txt)
[http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/uploader-broken/js/sample1.txt](http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/uploader-works/js/sample1.txt)

```
function FileProgress(file, targetID) {
    this.fileProgressID = file.id;

    this.opacity = 100;
    this.height = 0;


    this.fileProgressWrapper = document.getElementById(this.fileProgressID);
    if (!this.fileProgressWrapper) {
        this.fileProgressWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        this.fileProgressWrapper.className = "progressWrapper";
        this.fileProgressWrapper.id = this.fileProgressID;

        this.fileProgressElement = document.createElement("div");
        this.fileProgressElement.className = "progressContainer";
        //this.fileProgressElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Upload Status"));

        var progressCancel = document.createElement("a");
        progressCancel.className = "progressCancel";
        progressCancel.href = "#";
        progressCancel.style.visibility = "hidden";
        progressCancel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));

        var progressText = document.createElement("div");
        progressText.className = "progressName";
        progressText.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.name));

        var progressBar = document.createElement("div");
        progressBar.className = "progressBarInProgress";

        var progressStatus = document.createElement("div");
        progressStatus.className = "progressBarStatus";
        progressStatus.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

        var progressFull = document.createElement("div");
        progressFull.className = "progressBarFull";
        progressFull.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

        this.fileProgressElement.appendChild(progressCancel);
        this.fileProgressElement.appendChild(progressText);
        this.fileProgressElement.appendChild(progressStatus);
        this.fileProgressElement.appendChild(progressBar);
        this.fileProgressElement.appendChild(progressFull);
        this.fileProgressWrapper.appendChild(this.fileProgressElement);

        document.getElementById(targetID).appendChild(this.fileProgressWrapper);
    } else {
        this.fileProgressElement = this.fileProgressWrapper.firstChild;
        this.reset();
    }

    this.height = this.fileProgressWrapper.offsetHeight;
    this.setTimer(null);


}
```

Comment: "this line will break the presentation" break in what way? I've tested both versions with firefox 3.0.x and IE8 and didn't see anything obviously broken/wrong.

Comment: the question i ask in every DOM manipulation problem: are you sure that the DOM is loaded?

Comment: They appear identical to me: each one uploaded to around 45%, then locked up. Closing the tab caused my browser to freeze for several seconds. Chrome 2 on WinXP SP3.

Comment: it looks like timing to me, if you wait few lines down you will get your result, but i do agree with George, you have to check the element first before you append to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work any better?

```
this.fileProgressElement.innerHTML="Upload Status";
```